# How to download fast lots of web pages in ruby? Parallelizing download?

Tags: ruby, download, parallel-processing, wget

I need to scrape(using scrAPI) 400+ web pages ruby, my actual code is very sequential:

```
data = urls.map {|url| scraper.scrape url }
```

Actually the code is a bit different (exception handling and stuff).

How can I make it faster?
How can I parallelize the downloads?

Comment: Do you need to worry about hitting the server with too many requests at once?

Comment: https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus

Answer (score 5):

```
th = []
data = []
dlock = Mutex.new

urls.each do |url|
  th << Thread.new(url) do |url|
    d = scraper.scrape url
    dlock.synchronize { data << d }
  end
end

th.each { |t| t.join }
```

Tada!  (Caution; written from memory, not tested, may eat your kitten, etc)

**Edit:** I figured someone must have written a generalised version of this, and so they have: http://peach.rubyforge.org/ -- enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much an example used in the Pickaxe explanation of threading:

http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/tut_threads.html

You should be able to adapt the Pickaxe code trivially to use your scraper.